# How can I test for compatibility with EdgeHTML 13?

Tags: cross-browser, microsoft-edge

I'm doing cross browser testing and can't find a way to test with the MS Edge browser versions with EdgeHTML 13 (from late 2015).

My site is rendering properly in more recent versions of MS Edge, which I can test on BrowserStack and https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On August 2, instances of Edge 13 will be updated to Edge 14 via the [Anniversary Update](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2016/06/29/windows-10-anniversary-update-available-august-2/).

A cursory check reveals that SauceLabs has Edge 13 for testing, as does [BrowserStack](https://www.browserstack.com/list-of-browsers-and-platforms?product=live).